# How to do dependencies injection in class servlet?

Tags: java, servlets

I have two servlets, and both use same object for work with database. But using constructor or setter for injection reference to object impossible. Help me please, how to do this in my case:

First Servlet:

```
public class AddUserServlet extends HttpServlet {

    private DBJointPool db; // Как передать этот объект в класс?

    @Override
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws ServletException, IOException {

        db.somethingToDoWithDatabaseConnectionPool();

    }
}
```

Second Servlet:

```
public class DeleteUserServlet extends HttpServlet {

    private DBJointPool db; // Как передать этот объект в класс?

    @Override
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws ServletException, IOException {

        db.somethingToDoWithDatabaseConnectionPool();

    }
}
```

I use JDBC driver without framework.

Comment: suppose you refer this [example](http://www.journaldev.com/1997/servlet-jdbc-database-connection-example) which explains a good solution for your issue.

Comment: Is there a specific reason you're not using a framework?

Comment: @RajithPemabandu but that still is not dependency injection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `spring-boot` is included in your project, here would be the solution for your requirement:

```
@Bean
public ServletRegistrationBean addUserServlet(DBJointPool db) {
    // suppose there is a constructor for your servlet
    final ServletRegistrationBean servlet = new ServletRegistrationBean(new AddUserServlet(db));
    servlet.setName("addUserServlet");
    servlet.setUrlMappings(Collections.singletonList("/addUser.*"));
    return servlet;
}
```

And expose `DeleteUserServlet` as following:

```
@Bean
public ServletRegistrationBean deleteUserServlet(DBJointPool db) {
    // suppose there is a constructor for your servlet
    final ServletRegistrationBean servlet = new ServletRegistrationBean(new DeleteUserServlet(db));
    servlet.setName("deleteUserServlet");
    servlet.setUrlMappings(Collections.singletonList("/deleteUser.*"));
    return servlet;
}
```

Of course, you have to expose `DBJointPool` somewhere else, for example:

```
@Bean
public DBJointPool dBJointPool() {
    return new DBJointPool();
}
```

However, if you are not using `spring-boot` but `spring` framework is acceptable, then configure these beans in application context xml file would also work.

At last, if `spring` is not acceptable, please consider singletons, such as `static` member for these instances.

Please let me know if any problems.

Comment: Thank you, i don't use Spring. Sorry I'm forget write it in my question. Spring it's next chapter in my java learning. Don't delete you answer, i think  it's great case for future.

Comment: Then static instance for these beans can solve your problem.